# How to bring SOAP capability to payara/micro in EJB project

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, soap, glassfish, payara-micro

I have an EJB project providing webservices (both SOAP and REST) running inside a container with payara/micro as base image, since payara/micro does not come with JAXWS(SOAP support) feature out of the box, however, by adding

```
cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws
```

and

```
cxf-rt-transports-http
```

as dependencies into the project as well as following [this tutorial](https://www.javatips.net/blog/cxf-soap-without-spring) and put the following code instead:

```
@Override
public void loadBus(ServletConfig servletConfig) {
  super.loadBus(servletConfig);
  Bus bus = getBus();
  BusFactory.setDefaultBus(bus);
  Endpoint.publish("/MySoapService", new ASoapService());
}
```

I was able to make the SOAP interface almost available (wsdl information is publicly available already), and

```
http://localhost:8080/<my project name>/services
```

event listed out the available services as well their available methods and endpoints/WSDL/Target namespace information.

But when trying to access the SOAP service via SOAP client, I got on the server side errors with the following line of info:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.ASoapService.getXxx
...
```

Where

```
ASoapService
```

Is Actually an EJB. So I tried instead to replace the above code with the following:

```
@EJB
ASoapService aSoapService
...
Endpoint.publish("/MySoapService", aSoapService);
```

During startup of container, I got

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: com.example.ASoapServiceF#com.example.ASoapService not found
```

By checking the logs, I found a possible reason:
When SOAP part starts up with the following code

```
Endpoint.publish("/MySoapService", aSoapService);
```

The EJB Container is not yet ready and thus the lookup of

```
ASoapService
```

failed, is such assumption correct? Because normally you should see something like:

```
[2018-02-02T14:43:57.821+0000] [] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1517582637821] [levelValue: 800] Portable JNDI names for EJB ASoapService: [java:global/<my project name>/ASoapService, java:global/<my project name>/ASoapService!com.example.ASoapService]
```

during start up, which is not the case for my situation.

I am relatively new to EJB and Glassfish world, can I somehow force EJB container to start first? Or does it actually have anything to do with the starting sequence? How to combine the two together?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be trying to force EJB container to start. Instead, try one of the following:

- instead of `@EJB ASoapService aSoapService` to inject the EJB try `@Inject
  ASoapService aSoapService` - `@Inject` should wait for the dependencies therefore wait until the EJB is available
- run the method `Endpoint.publish` from an object which is initialized after EJB container is ready, either from a startup singleton EJB or when CDI application scope is initialized: https://rmannibucau.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/cdi-and-startup/